# Not getting simple JS Link tutorials to work

Tags: jslink

I haven't had experience with JS Link and thought it would be a good idea to start learning it and try it out.  I found what I thought were pretty straightforward tutorials of how to use it.  First I tried using [these examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a), specifically the Priority Coloring and Percent Complete.

The first time around when I tried adding the JS Link file, my page turned white and stayed white.  I haven't found a solution to that yet besides deleting the view and creating a new one.  I tried doing this again and it seemed to have a successful connection as the completed checkbox in my task list changed from an actual checkbox to 'No'.  But the color of my priority fields didn't change.

I tried doing this in a different site to see if that made a difference and didn't notice anything.  I had similar results with the Percent Complete script.  I was initially placing these scripts in my Site Assets library and then tried placing them in the masterpage library like I found in [another tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8rLdnY2ZW8).

I would just like to successfully get a JS Link file to work on my list and then go from there.  Has anyone come across these issues or know what I need to do to fix them?

Comment: I don't know what the trouble you are having. I did this tutorial [here](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/) and got it to work.

Comment: How are you attaching the JSLink? I find WebPart properties unreliable. You need to use Powershell to attach to the view itself

Comment: for me, none of previous solutions was working. But when I changed the javascript file name, it works, but when I changed the content of the file and uploaded it again, none of changes was executed. It worked only if I changed the JavaScript file name again and again and...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work.  I had to use `~sitecollection/` to start the path in the JS Link field.  I wasn't using `~sitecollection/` before and was just using the path that I would generally use (`http://www.contoso.com/mysite/SiteAssets/filename.js`).  I don't quite understand why it works this way but this is what fixed my problem.

Here's the article that helped me figure this out.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/72e88ca7-af70-4769-9530-4b37d9b8c1d0/js-style-is-not-working-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization

Answer (score 2):

I also solved this issue by using a URL beginning with ~site/ instead of ~sitecollection/, so it may be the case that any relative URL is accepted by SharePoint.

Comment: you need to use one of the accepted tokens in the beggining. Any other relative URL and it won't work. I think they are: ~site, ~sitecollection, ~sitelayouts and ~sitecollectionlayouts